# Celery Flower not monitoring jobs

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, flower

I am running Celery and Flower, with RabbitMQ as a message broker. When I have no running workers and start a task, it sits on the queue until a worker starts. Then, when I start my workers, the task is consumed and executed as expected. However, when I try to use the Flower API to get task info, args and kwargs are null. This never happens when my workers are already running when I call a task. Why is this, and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Celery works, but with flower doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247062/celery-works-but-with-flower-doesnt-work)